# Add parameter to x-editable params

Tags: javascript, jquery, x-editable

x-editable has the `option()` method which is used to set a new option.  `params` is one of the options and happens to be an object, and instead of replacing `params` with a new object, I just want to add a property to the existing `params` object.  Below is my attempt, but I am inadvertently overwriting `params` and not adding a new property as desired.

http://jsfiddle.net/fo1susa1/

```
$(function() {

    $('#name').editable({
        url: '/echo/json/',
        pk: 123,
        params:{a:1,b:2}
    })
    .on('shown', function(e, editable) {
        editable.option('params', {c:3});
    });

});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add a property to the existing params object like this:

```
$(function() {

    $('#name').editable({
        url: '/echo/json/',
        pk: 123,
        params:{a:1,b:2}
    })
    .on('shown', function(e, editable) {
        editable.options.params.c = 3;
        // editable.options.params is now {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
    });

});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I started using the following.  I like your way more!  `var params = editable.options.params || {};params.c = 3;editable.option('params', params);`